# I am looking for a way to make ScrollView scale and pan in Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

The question is difficult to understand due to machine translation. Sorry.

I am looking for a way to make ScrollView scale and pan in Kotlin.

Current status: Scrolling and scaling have been implemented.

Goal: In addition to the current implementation, pan is possible when the view is zoomed in.

I am just starting to learn Kotlin, so I would greatly appreciate it if you could give me more details.

Here is the current code.

```
ktfile
 class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
 
     private var mScale = 1f
     private var mScaleGestureDetector: ScaleGestureDetector? = null
     var gestureDetector: GestureDetector? = null
 
     override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
 
         gestureDetector = GestureDetector(this, GestureListener())
         mScaleGestureDetector = ScaleGestureDetector(this, object : SimpleOnScaleGestureListener() {
 
             override fun onScale(detector: ScaleGestureDetector): Boolean {
 
                 var mScaleFactor = detector.scaleFactor
                 val prevScale = mScale
                 mScale /= mScaleFactor
                 println(mScale);
 
                 // we can maximise our focus to 10f only
                 if (mScale >= 1f) mScale = 1f
                 if (mScale <= 0.5f) mScale = 0.5f
                 val scaleAnimation = ScaleAnimation(
                     1f / prevScale,
                     1f / mScale,
                     1f / prevScale,
                     1f / mScale,
                     detector.focusX,
                     detector.focusY
                 )
 
                 scaleAnimation.duration = 0
                 scaleAnimation.fillAfter = true
 
                 val layout = findViewById<View>(R.id.scrollView) as ScrollView
 
                 layout.startAnimation(scaleAnimation)
                 return true
             }
         })
     }
 
     override fun dispatchTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
         super.dispatchTouchEvent(event)
 
         mScaleGestureDetector!!.onTouchEvent(event)
         gestureDetector!!.onTouchEvent(event)
         return gestureDetector!!.onTouchEvent(event)
     }
 
     private class GestureListener : SimpleOnGestureListener() {
         override fun onDown(e: MotionEvent): Boolean {
             return true
         }
 
         override fun onDoubleTap(e: MotionEvent): Boolean {
             return true
         }
     }
 }
```

```
xmlfile
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     tools:context=".MainActivity">
 
 
     <ScrollView
         android:id="@+id/scrollView"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
         app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
         app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
         app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
 
         <LinearLayout
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:orientation="vertical">
 
             <ImageView
                 android:id="@+id/image1"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:contentDescription="@string/no_image"
                 android:src="@drawable/image1"/>
 
             <ImageView
                 android:id="@+id/image2"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                 android:contentDescription="@string/no_image"
                 android:src="@drawable/image2" />
 
             <ImageView
                 android:id="@+id/image3"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                 android:contentDescription="@string/no_image"
                 android:src="@drawable/image3" />
 
             <ImageView
                 android:id="@+id/image4"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                 android:contentDescription="@string/no_image"
                 android:src="@drawable/image4" />
 
             <ImageView
                 android:id="@+id/image5"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                 android:contentDescription="@string/no_image"
                 android:src="@drawable/image5" />
 
             <ImageView
                 android:id="@+id/image6"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                 android:contentDescription="@string/no_image"
                 android:src="@drawable/image6" />
 
         </LinearLayout>
 
     </ScrollView>
 
 
 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private lateinit var mScaleGestureDetector: ScaleGestureDetector
private lateinit var mPanGestureDetector: GestureDetector

private var mScaleFactor = 1.0f
private var mTranslationX = 0f
private var mTranslationY = 0f
private var mImageWidth = 0f
private var mImageHeight = 0f
private var mDefaultImageWidth = 0f
private var mDefaultImageHeight = 0f
private var mViewPortWidth = 0f
private var mViewPortHeight = 0f

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    mImageView.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.hongkong))

    mScaleGestureDetector = ScaleGestureDetector(this, ScaleListener())
    mPanGestureDetector = GestureDetector(this, PanListener())

    val viewTreeObserver = mImageView.viewTreeObserver
    if (viewTreeObserver.isAlive) {
        viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(object : ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
            override fun onGlobalLayout() {
                mImageView.viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)

                val imageAspectRatio = mImageView.drawable.intrinsicHeight.toFloat() / mImageView.drawable.intrinsicWidth.toFloat()
                val viewAspectRatio = mImageView.height.toFloat() / mImageView.width.toFloat()

                mImageWidth =  scrollView.height.toFloat()
                mImageHeight =  scrollView.height.toFloat()

                mDefaultImageWidth = mImageWidth
                mDefaultImageHeight = mImageHeight

                mViewPortWidth = mImageView.width.toFloat()
                mViewPortHeight = mImageView.height.toFloat()
            }
        })
    }
}


override fun dispatchTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
    mScaleGestureDetector!!.onTouchEvent(event)
    mPanGestureDetector!!.onTouchEvent(event)

    return mPanGestureDetector!!.onTouchEvent(event)
}

private inner class PanListener : GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
    override fun onScroll(
        e1: MotionEvent, e2: MotionEvent,
        distanceX: Float, distanceY: Float
    ): Boolean {
        val translationX = mTranslationX - distanceX
        val translationY = mTranslationY - distanceY

        adjustTranslation(translationX, translationY)

        return true
    }
}

private inner class ScaleListener : ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener() {
    override fun onScale(detector: ScaleGestureDetector): Boolean {
        mScaleFactor *= mScaleGestureDetector.scaleFactor
        mScaleFactor = Math.max(1.0f, Math.min(mScaleFactor, 5.0f))
        mImageView.scaleX = mScaleFactor
        mImageView.scaleY = mScaleFactor
        mImageWidth = mDefaultImageWidth * mScaleFactor
        mImageHeight = mDefaultImageHeight * mScaleFactor

        adjustTranslation(mTranslationX, mTranslationY)

        return true
    }
}

private fun adjustTranslation(translationX: Float, translationY: Float) {
    val translationXMargin = Math.abs((mImageWidth - mViewPortWidth) / 2)
    val translationYMargin = Math.abs((mImageHeight - mViewPortHeight) / 2)

    if (translationX < 0) {
        mTranslationX = Math.max(translationX, -translationXMargin)
    } else {
        mTranslationX = Math.min(translationX, translationXMargin)
    }

    if (mTranslationY < 0) {
        mTranslationY = Math.max(translationY, -translationYMargin)
    } else {
        mTranslationY = Math.min(translationY, translationYMargin)
    }

    scrollview.translationX = mTranslationX
    scrollview.translationY = mTranslationY
}
```

}

I was able to resolve it myself.
The above code was used to address the issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).